# How to connect a Belkin modem to a Belkin router to complicated home network with a web server

Tags: router, home-networking, webserver, modem

I came back from a trip to find my Linksys modem/router had partially fried itself. So I went to the local "big box" electronics store for a quick fix. After a bit of faffing they sold me a Belkin N750DB router and a Belkin ADSL2+ single port modem for the price of the router as they didn't have the router I wanted in stock.

Our home network consists of a few laptops and mobile devices, a VOIP box, a NAS box, a Playstation 3, and a small web server I use for personal projects. With the Linksys I had placed the web server in the DMZ and used port forwarding for a few PS3 specific ports. I also hard-coded the DNS to point at the Google DNS servers.

Having successfully daisy chained modems to routers in the past I didn't think I'd have any issues... three hours later I am going a bit nuts. I have got it to the point it can connect to the internet but the DNS won't resolve properly inside the network.

How should I configure all of these devices so the web server is sitting in DMZ, is visible to the outside world, my PS3 can use port forwarding where required, and DNS resolves from inside the network?

I'm happy to set the core devices to static IPs but I'd like to maintain a DHCP pool for the laptops and mobile devices.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you confirm the DNS server set on your devices is the same as the gateway? That should be the router IP.

Comment: Hi Bob. Yes, the DHCP clients have their DNS servers set to the router ip.

Comment: does dns query return nothing or wroing IP?

Comment: Hi Vineet. The DNS was unable to resolve to any IP. I think I may have fixed it today.